# Jquery slide plugin text on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel-2

I'm using slider plugin: owlcarousel2. The problem that i want the

text to be on the picture not in next slide. I want also the div tag to group elements, not to be ignored.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<head>
<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden}
img{

width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
p{
background-color:black;
opacity:0.7;
z-index:9999
}
</style>
<div class="owl-carousel">
<div>
<img src='img.jpeg' alt='Hi!'></a>
<p class='text'>hi</p>
</div>
</div>


</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:false,
      items:1,
    center:true



})
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is fine, but there are some other mistakes that prevent it from working. I'll walk you through it. First, close your `<head>` and wrap the carousel in `<body>` tags. Remove the rogue `</a>` after the slide image and the unnecessary `</div>` located just before the script at the bottom.

To get the text on top of the image you can set an absolute position on the paragraph element and a relative position on it's parent.

Here's what your code should look like after these adjustments:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      loop: true,
      margin: 10,
      nav: false,
      items: 1,
      center: true
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f00;
}
p {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src='img.jpeg' alt='Hi!'>
      <p class='text'>hi</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```